# How to run program in DevC++ and with space in file path?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I am trying to use Dev-C++ but it is not working since I can not run programs with space in file path. It looks that somebody forget that such character is often used.

I can compile code without problem but I can not run it.

```
--------------------------------
Failed to execute "C:\Users\Crezary Wagner\Desktop\c++\multi.exe":
Error 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Program is valid but in "Crezary Wagner" is space and there is problem for modern IDE :) How to fix it?

Comment: You can run the program from a command interpreter. To make DevC++ do the Right Thing, make sure its program invocation uses a quoted path. It should be " double-quote characters.

Comment: However, since Code::Blocks has problems dealing with project directories that has paths with spaces, maybe DevC++ also is a bit challenged in that respect. It would be a good idea to make sure the project directory has path without spaces, and without pesky national characters. Windows tools generally have no problems, though, so a different solution is to just use Visual Studio.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I think it is very strange that this bug can not be fixed.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Visual C++ not use g++ so code can be not same.

Answer (score 1):

if you are giving this path as some string argument, you can append  **\"**

character to the starting and ending points of the string:

```
program2runStr = "\"" + program2runStr + "\"";
```

Comment: That is true but why Dev-C++ not works and how it can be fixed?

Comment: if you are giving this path as an input to the process to be started in runtime in the code, the compiler can not differentiate it from any other program input argument

Comment: it will be the same on any other compiler and ide

Comment: I just want solve this problem in Dev-C++. I can not run program if path use "modern space" - old programs 20 years ago has problem with it but why 2015 compilation has such program I have not idea :)